# Selenium doesn't find element loaded from Ajax

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to get access to the 4 images on this page: https://altkirch-alsace.fr/serviable/demarches-en-ligne/prendre-un-rdv-cni/

However the grey region seems to be Ajax-loaded (according to its class name). I want to get the element `<div id="prestations">` inside of it but can't access it, nor any other element within the grey area.

I have tried to follow several answers to similar questions, but no matter how long I wait I get an error that the element is not found ; the element is here when I click "Inspect element" but I don't see it when I click "View source". Does that mean I can't access it through selenium?

Here is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://altkirch-alsace.fr/serviable/demarches-en-ligne/prendre-un-rdv-cni/")

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) \
    .until(lambda x: x.find_element(By.ID, "prestations")) 
print(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using  `WebDriverWait(...).until` properly. Your lambda is using `find_element`, which throws exception when it is called and the element is not found.

You should use it like this instead:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
...
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "prestations"))
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem. There is no issue with waiting. There is a frame on that webpage:

```
<iframe src="https://www.rdv360.com/mairie-d-altkirch?ajx_md=1" width="100%"
 height="600" style="border:0px;"></iframe>
```

The Document Object Model - DOM of the main website does not contain any informations about the webpage that is loaded into a frame.
Even waiting hours you will not find any elements inside this frame, as it has its own DOM.

You need to switch the WebDriver context to this frame. Than you may access the frame's DOM:

As on your website the iframe has no id, you may search for all frames like described on the selenium webpage (https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/frames/):
The code searches for all HTML-tags of type "iframe" and takes the first (maybe it should be [0] not [1])

```
iframe = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'iframe')[1]
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Now you may find your desired elements.

The solution that worked in my case on a webpage like this:

```
<html>
...
<iframe ... id="myframe1">
...
<\iframe>
<iframe ... id="myframe2">
...
<\iframe>
...
</html>
```

```
my_iframe = my_WebDriver.find_element(By.ID, 'myframe_1')
my_Webdriver.swith_to.frame(my_iframe)
```

also working:

```
my_WebDriver.switch_to.frame('myframe_1')
```

According Selenium docs you may use iframe's name, id or the element itself to switch to that frame.